# Are these two if statements the same?

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

1)

`if (((w || x) || y) || z)`

2)

`if (w || x || y || z)`

I see the first one in a lot of code I'm working on and I'm wondering if I can simplify it to the second one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the two statements are equivalent.

[7.2.1 Operator precedence and associativity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> When an operand occurs between two operators with the same precedence, the associativity of the operators controls the order in which the operations are performed:
>
> - Except for the assignment operators, all binary operators are left-associative, meaning that operations are performed from left to right. For example, x + y + z is evaluated as (x + y) + z.

Comment: Am I being dumb? Where does `x + y * z` stand in this?

Comment: Ah: "When an operand occurs between two operators with the same precedence" the statement above applies. Might be worth adding to your answer, because taken in isolation, your quote is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

in short, in the first statement, you are checking if any of w,x,y, or z are true.  Therefore, the second statement is in fact equivalent to the first.